# Run Jenkins job after success of another Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have 2 Jenkins jobs(on Jenkins 2.0) - **job A to merge on git repo myCode** and **job B to run integration test from Git repo MyTestRun**. myCode has a webhook configured for Push Event. *Both the jobs have Build Trigger - GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling*.

I want to configure my jobs such that when there is a push on git repo myCode, Job B is executed first and Job A is run after successful completion of Job B.

Answer (score 2):

Either you could use the already mentioned pipeline plugin and write something like this:

```
stage('merge') {
  'job A' : { build job: 'job A'; }
}

stage('integration test') {
  'job B' : { build job: 'job B'; }
}
```

or if you do not need the pipeline, you could use the plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

The config would look like this:

[image: jenkins config]

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to take advantage of a plug-in feature that allows you to create pipelines. There are many ways to implement these as well as multiple plugins that allow for this functionality. Pipeline is the term that will be useful for you to look into.  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/